# Mac Terminal freezes when processing syllables from word file

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I am using a for loop to copy words syllabilized in a new text file from another text file. The terminal freezes after copying half of the words which are 100k where each in a line without showing any errors. What is happening with the system?

```
from syltippy import syllabize
from collections import Counter 


with open('espanol.txt', 'r', encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as DictEspanol, open('espanolSYLL.txt', 'w+') as DictEspanol2:
  
    for word in DictEspanol:
        word=str(word)
        syllables, stress = syllabize(word)
        DictEspanol2.write(u'-'.join(s if stress != i else s.upper() for (i, s) in enumerate(syllables)))
        DictEspanol2.write("\n")
        
    DictEspanol2.close()
    print('DOONNEE')
with open('espanolSYLL.txt', 'rb') as DictEspanol2, open('espanolSYLL2.txt', 'w+') as DictEspanol3:  
    print('done')
    for word in DictEspanol2:
        print('done 2')
        Lettercount=word
        counter = Lettercount.count('-')
        print(counter)
        
        if counter == 2:
            print(word)
            DictEspanol3.write(word)
            DictEspanol3.write("\n")

print('Donney Donney ')
```

Comment: Which of the prints you have added do you see as output on the terminal?

Comment: @mkrieger1 none! I added as a print in the loop but I removed it. It used to show in the terminal but it stops showing after copying half of the words.

Comment: Why do you read in mode `rb` for the 2nd loop?  This makes the 2nd `for` loop read a chunk of some size looking for some newline, not necessarily the same as what a text read would do.  Try opening with just `r`?